# WPF DataGrid Filtering - CollectionViewSource Refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I want to know how I can refresh a CollectionViewSource when a button is clicked?

So far I have

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCustomers"
                          Source="{Binding CustomerCollection}" 
                          Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" >
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Which creates the CollectionViewSource...

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="210" 
              Margin="47,153,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCustomers}}"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
```

Which binds the source to my Datagrid

```
    private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Customer t = e.Item as Customer;
        if (t != null)
        // If filter is turned on, filter completed items.
        {
            if (t.Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And a filter in my View,

Everything seems to be working (items are being bounded to the grid) but how do I refresh the view or grid so I can fire of the above function again so the grid does get filtered? (by a button click really)

Thanks

Comment: Your question differed from the example I was following in a subtle way that allowed me to arrive at the reason why my view was not refreshing when I compared what you were attempting to my effort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call **`Refresh()`** on **`View`** property of **`CollectionViewSource`** to get it refreshed.

In case you want to do it on button click, you need to access CollectionViewSource from window resources first and then call refresh on its View.

```
((CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["cvsCustomers"]).View.Refresh();
```

Comment: Since .Net 4.5 you can add 
`IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" 
IsLiveSortingRequested="True"`
properties to XAML CollectionViewSource definition to refresh automatically
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515053/datagrid-grouping-doesnt-update-on-change-in-collectionviewsource

Comment: @Chashitsu So how does it know my filter TextBox change? What magic make it knows the TextBox change so it can refresh automatically?