# How to implement an editable DataGrid that updates its content on the fly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am using a `DataGrid` to present data from a `List<VideoFile>` containing objects with mostly string properties describing a video file like title, runtime, quality etc. I want to be able to arrange and edit displayed data via the `DataGrid` and refresh `DataGrid` content on the fly. I'm new to WPF so i've read multiple threads on the topic and i am pretty confused what is the best (least complex, fastest) way to achieve this.

My current implementation:

```
GlobalVariables.List1 = Program.LoadFromXML(GlobalVariables.DatabaseLocation);
GlobalVariables.itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
GlobalVariables.itemCollectionViewSource.Source = GlobalVariables.List1;
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSource"  
        CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
</Window.Resources>


<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryDisplay"
          Margin="10,10,10,0"
          Height="527" Width="715" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"       
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          IsReadOnly="False" 
          SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" 
          CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" 
         />
```

AutoGenerateColums is set temporarily. Here is a part of how it looks:

[image: DataGrid look]

Comment: You can try to use ObservableCollection<T> as source to your CollectionViewSource. I am sure about your datasource from the above code.

Comment: Try the following link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081088/wpf-datagrid-filtering-refreshing-collectionviewsource-refreshing
Or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034840/handling-onpropertychanged

Comment: @Telimaktar Thx the links u posted solved my case though i wasnt certain if CollectionViewSource is the right path to follow and so i asked the question.