# DataGrid grouping doesn't update on change in CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I have a CollectionViewSource `CollectionOfVideos` bound to ObservableCollection `ListOfVideos`. That CollectionViewSource is the ItemsSource for the DataGrid `dataGrid_Video`. I've implemented a grouping by `lShortName` of `label` of `ListOfVideos`. When items are added to DataGrid, grouping seems to work, because it groups all added items by their default `label`.

Problem is, grouping doesn't update when `label` of item is changed. Here's my code:

**Window.Resources in MainWindow.xaml**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionOfVideos" Source="{Binding fosaModel.ListOfVideos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" >
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="label" Converter="{StaticResource LTSConverter}"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="label.lShortName"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

**dataGrid_Video in MainWindow.xaml**

```
       <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Video" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionOfVideos}}" 
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
          SelectedItem="{Binding fosaModel.SelectedVideo}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding fosaModel.SelectedVideoIndex}"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding fName}" Header="Nazwa" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AudioToSync}" Header="Dźwięk"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

Here's my fosaModel

```
   public class fosaModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<fosaVideo> ListOfVideos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<fosaVideo>();
        public ObservableCollection<fosaAudio> ListOfAudios { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<fosaAudio>();
        public ObservableCollection<fosaLabel> ListOfLabels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<fosaLabel>();
        public fosaVideo SelectedVideo { get; set; }
        public int SelectedVideoIndex { get; set; } = -1;
        public fosaAudio SelectedAudio { get; set; }
        public int SelectedAudioIndex { get; set; } = -1;
        public fosaLabel SelectedLabel { get; set; }
        public int SelectedLabelIndex { get; set; } = -1;
        public string WorkingDir { get; set; } = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        public double videoProgress { get; set; }
        public int SliderValue { get; set; }
        public bool IsDialogClosed { get; set; } = true;

    }
```

---

There are few things you should know:

- I use Fody.PropertyChanged, so it's not PropertyChanged notification problem. Adding new items to the list updates the DataGrid.
- Sorting doesn't work either.
- Changing `label` of particular item in `ListOfVideos` does work, I checked in Debug
- I thought it was a problem with dot notation of `PropertyName` in GroupingDescriptions, so I've added a converter. With or without converter - problem still exists.
- There is also very similar CollectionViewSource, with sorting implemented, and it works on adding new item.
- I use MVVM Light and I'd like to keep it MVVM way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the names of the properties to live group by to the LiveGroupingProperties collection of the CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionOfVideos" Source="{Binding fosaModel.ListOfVideos, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" IsLiveSortingRequested="True"
                              xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
        <s:String>label</s:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="label" Converter="{StaticResource LTSConverter}"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

It's the same for the live sorting: https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/16/988-enabling-live-sorting-in-a-collectionviewsource/

I don't think this will work with nested properties such as "label.lShortName" though so if you want to live sort by a sub-property of the type `T` in your `ObservableCollection<T>` you need to add a property to the type `T` that wraps the sub-property, e.g.:

```
public string lShortName
{
    get { return label.lShortName; }
    set { label.lShortName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a class of ListOfVideos worked just fine, I didn't even have to add those LiveGroupingProperties. So it turned out to be PropertyChanged problem. Much thanks!